# How to delete a label after a keypress

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label, runtime-error

I am trying to remove a label after a player presses any key. However, the Python shell displays an error message. How do I fix this?

I have tried `label.destroy()`, but since I already have a label that calls this function, the `label.destroy()` function does not work.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def testing(event):
    print("You have pressed a key.")
    root.unbind_all('<Key>')
    label.destroy() # There are two of these.

def countdown(count, label):
    label['text'] = count
    if count > -1:
        root.after(1000, countdown, count-1, label)
    elif count == 0:
        label['text'] = 'Time \nExpired'
    elif count < 0:
        label.destroy() # The second "label.destroy()"

# any_key = root.create_text(250, 400, anchor=CENTER, font=('Calibri', 20), text='Press any key to start.')
# I commented the previous line out because that was my previous code.

any_key = Label(root, anchor=CENTER, font=('Calibri', 20), text='Press any key to start.')
any_key.place(250, 400) # Error 2

root.bind('<Key>', testing)
label = Label(root, anchor=CENTER, font=('Calibri', 48))
label.place(x=50, y=100)
countdown(10, label)

root.bind_all('<Key>', testing)

root.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I was hoping that this program would remove the label named `any_key`, but it did not even show up before I pressed a key. Additionally, Tkinter shows an error that displays `TypeError: place_configure() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`, even though I only gave 2 arguments for placing the `any_key` label. If you comment out `any_key.place()`, another error shows up, reading:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 749, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "Python\Python37\Programs\Tests\test 8.py", line 22, in countdown
    label['text'] = count
  File "Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1492, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1485, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas.!label2"
```

How do I fix these errors?

Comment: always show full error message - full Traceback - in question. There are many useful information. And don't expect that we will run code to see error

Comment: `place()` expects arguments with names - like in other line of your code `label.place(x=50, y=100)`

Comment: when `count` is zero then it executes `if count > -1`, not `if count == 0`

Comment: you didn't create `root` - ie. `root = tk.Tk()` - so it doesn't works on my conmputer.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I also changed my question to include the full error message.

Comment: you can't do `root.pack()` because it makes no sense - you can't put window inside the same window or any other window.

Comment: @furas I am confused by what you said. Could you explain further?

Comment: `root` is main window (`Tk()` creates main window). Using `pack()`/`place()`/`grid()` you put widgets in window `root`. And using `root.pack()` you try to put window `root` inside window `root` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changes which I described in comments I get working code

`place` needs arguments with names `place(x=..., y=...)`

`root.pack()` will not works - `root` doesn't have method `pack()`. You can't put window `root` inside window `root`.

I also use `count > 0` instead of `count > -1` and now it can check `count == 0`

```
from tkinter import *

def testing(event):
    print("You have pressed a key.")
    root.unbind_all('<Key>')
    label.destroy() # There are two of these.

def countdown(count, label):
    label['text'] = count
    if count > 0: # not -1
        root.after(1000, countdown, count-1, label)
    elif count == 0:
        label['text'] = 'Time \nExpired'
        # to destroy after 1s
        root.after(1000, countdown, count-1, label)
    elif count < 0:
        label.destroy() # The second "label.destroy()"

root = Tk()

any_key = Label(root, anchor=CENTER, font=('Calibri', 20), text='Press any key to start.')
any_key.place(x=250, y=400) # need x=, y=

label = Label(root, anchor=CENTER, font=('Calibri', 48))
label.place(x=50, y=100)
countdown(10, label)

root.bind_all('<Key>', testing)
#root.pack() # you try to put window `root` inside window `root`

root.mainloop()
```

Because you can destroy label in `testing()` before it ends countdown so it could be good to inform `countdown` that widget doesn't exists. I will use `label = None` for this

```
def testing(event):
    global label

    print("You have pressed a key.")

    root.unbind_all('<Key>')

    if label is not None:
         label.destroy() # There are two of these.
         label = None


def countdown(count, label):
    global label

    if label is not None:
        label['text'] = count
        if count > 0: # not -1
            root.after(1000, countdown, count-1, label)
        elif count == 0:
            label['text'] = 'Time \nExpired'
            # to destroy after 1s
            root.after(1000, countdown, count-1, label)
        elif count < 0:
            label.destroy() # The second "label.destroy()"
            label = None
```

Comment: I just tested your code. When I press a key, it removes the `countdown` label, rather than the `any_key` label.

Comment: then use `any_key.destroy()` instead of `label.destroy()`

Answer (score -1):

For solve the ERROR 2 you should do this:

```
any_key.place(x=250, y=400) # SOLVE ERROR
```

I have also an error on this: "root.pack()" because should be "label.pack()"

Do two times destroy because there are two line "root.bind('', testing)" and "root.bind_all('', testing)" keep only one.

The error in console happen because the two methods "testing" and "countdown" are async and so countdown start before testing and try to do something on label after his destroy.
So you need to synchronize this method and share the state of the lable (also with label == null)

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import functools

root = Tk()
state = True

def synchronized(wrapped):
    lock = threading.Lock()
    @functools.wraps(wrapped)
    def _wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Calling '%s' with Lock %s" % (wrapped.__name__, id(lock)))
        with lock:
            return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrap

@synchronized
def testing(event):
    global state
    print(event)
    print("You have pressed a key.")
    root.unbind_all('<Key>')
    state = False
    label.destroy() # There are two of these.

@synchronized
def countdown(count, label):
    global state
    print(count)
    print(state)
    if state: 
        label['text'] = count
        if count > 0:
            root.after(1000, countdown, count-1, label)
        elif count == 0:
            label['text'] = 'Time \nExpired'
        elif count < 0:
            label.destroy() # The second "label.destroy()"

# any_key = root.create_text(250, 400, anchor=CENTER, font=('Calibri', 20), text='Press any key to start.')
# I commented the previous line out because that was my previous code.

any_key = Label(root, anchor=CENTER, font=('Calibri', 20), text='Press any key to start.')
any_key.place(x=250, y=400) # SOLVE ERROR

root.bind('<Key>', testing)
label = Label(root, anchor=CENTER, font=('Calibri', 48))
label.place(x=50, y=100)
countdown(10, label)



label.pack() # SOLVE ERROR
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are the other two modules built into python?

Comment: it is too complicated.

Comment: @furas I know but take into account all possibile concurrent situation

Comment: @18ballz yes they are into default lib